# Feature Importance and Threshold Moving

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, xgboost, class-imbalance

Problem Type : Binary Classification
Dataset : Imbalanced

Current sklearn pipeline uses XGBoost model and involves moving threshold from 0.5 to a considerably higher value like 0.8 - 0.9.

Is it viable to use XGBoost's feature importance metrics for identifying the relevant features, if not what would be a better alternate?

Comment: xgb feature importances don't care about the decision threshold, I think

Comment: The metric to judge the classifier is identifying right set of features or assigning the correct importance would be to see its performance (precision, recall etc.). If I am moving the threshold by such a great extent, my hunch is that the classifier is not doing the job correctly and hence not identifying the features correctly.
Any thoughts?